# Find availible API endpoints, given root access to webserver

Tags: apache-http-server, curl, api, web-application

I have root access to a web/application server, which is located on my local LAN. I can see some API endpoints via logging on the server and hit them via curl. I would like to know all available endpoints. Is it possible to enumerate that?

To be more clear. This server runs a web application, when I click a button in the UI to make some change I can see the request in the application's log telling me the API endpoint I hit. I can then use that information to compose a curl command and perform the same action without using the UI.

I would like to find all available endpoints, and given this is an app on my network that I have root access to, I thought that would be possible.

The server runs apache, and API requests are  to HTTP://serverIP/api/api.php; an example endpoint would look like /v2/action/class/thing

Answer (score 0):

This information is not available unless the application explicitly implements it.

If you have access to the source code, you may be able to search it efficiently based on some patterns or use framework's built-in routing listing feature. Specifics depend on the framework and/or language used.

Some APIs designed for general public (ie. not designed exclusively for an app) can provide standardized documentation in Schema.org or Swagger/OpenAPI formats.